# Android studio unable to locate ADB although it is in the platform tools foldder

Tags: android

I know this seems like a common but I tried every solution I found.
My problem is that the adb foldder is in the platform tools foldder but everytime I try to connect a phone to my computer and run my app
I get No Devices at the the top.
Then Troubleshoot shows me unable to locate ADB.
I deleted the platform tools foldder in android studio, on my computer and reinstalled it but it still doesnt work.
I even deleted Android studio and reinstalled it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTR99.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You can try to open a terminal and type in

```
adb devices
```

to see whether ADB is installed and running well.

It's working if it shows "List of devices attached", then you can go to Windows search box, find and open Activity Monitor, under CPU tag, find adb, select it and Force Quit the process(quit them all if there are several of them).

Then restart AS to see whether your device is connected.

Comment: Thank you but it shows something like this command is spelled wrong or cannot be found

Comment: My computer cannot find the drivers for adb Interface and for CDC Serial

Comment: This did narrow down the problem. You can check the Android SDK, which is in Android Studio->Tools->Android SDK, to see whether it's installed properly. If not, download the latest version, otherwise, open the Android SDK Location in Windows File Explorer, in platform-tools folder, to check whether there's a adb.exe file.

Comment: If the SDK and adb file is all set, try adding the platform-tools directory into Windows Path environment variables, it should make the adb command work

Comment: Thank you very much in the end i had to install an universal adb driver